# DioError [DioErrorType.response] Http status error [404] - flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dio

```
 DioError [DioErrorType.response] Http status error [404] - flutter
```

I'm creating a forget password screen for my app. I want to display "email sent" message when I click "Reset password " button.. instead of that ,I'm getting above error when I'm enter already registered  email address. postman request is successfully working. how to solve this issue. appreciate your help on this.

[image: postman response]

```
   import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:doctor_app/constants/Button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';

import '../constants/colors.dart';

class ForgetPassword extends StatelessWidget {
  const ForgetPassword({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.leanBack);
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text('DOCTOR',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                      fontSize: 30,
                      color: Color(0xff05ABA3),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Text('Forgot your password?',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    height: 1.2,
                    fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Color(0xff040000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  )),
            ]),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Confirm your email and we will send the Instructions ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      height: 1.2,
                      fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Color(0xff707070),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),

            ForgetPasswordForm(), //email
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'didnt receive an email?',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    height: 1.2,
                    fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          // add action here whatever you want.
                        },
                        child: Text('send again  ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              height: 1.2,
                              fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                              fontSize: 13,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ))))
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    color: Color(0xff05ABA3),
                  ),
                  height: 5,
                  width: 120,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ForgetPasswordForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const ForgetPasswordForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ForgetPasswordFormState createState() => _ForgetPasswordFormState();
}

class _ForgetPasswordFormState extends State<ForgetPasswordForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  //String _userName = "";
  String email = "";

  Future Resetpassword() async {
    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(
          'https://doctor-app2-hit.herokuapp.com/user/forgotpassword',
          data: {
            "email": email,
          });

      if (response.data["data"] ==
          "Please check your email to reset password.") {
        Get.snackbar("success", "Email Sent Successfully!");
        //Get.to(VideoScreen());

      }else{
        Get.snackbar("error", "No User Found");
      }
      print("res: $response");
    } catch (e) {

      Get.snackbar("error", "Server Error");
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
            child: Container(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Container(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  child: Column(children: [
                    TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Email",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: textGrey,
                                fontFamily: "Dubai",
                                fontSize: 14)),
                        validator: (String? Email) {
                          if (Email != null && Email.isEmpty) {
                            return "Email can't be empty";
                          }
                          return null;
                        }),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: ButtonM("Reset Password"),
                        onTap: () async {
                          Resetpassword();
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
                )))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 is thrown since the endpoint you are trying to call cannot be found. Notice that the URL you try to call has two forward slashes before the `user` path.

Change this: `https://doctor-app2-hit.herokuapp.com//user/forgotpassword`
to this: `https://doctor-app2-hit.herokuapp.com/user/forgotpassword`

Comment: corrected. but still throws same error

Comment: Then, double-check what you pass to the request body (data), maybe you pass an empty email to the body. Just do some debugging to verify that.

Comment: you are not assigning any value to String email  variable please check agin